# Ansible: wait_for in with_items

Tags: ansible

I have a set of web server processes that I wish to restart one at a time. I want to wait for process N to be ready to service HTTP requests before restarting process N+1

The following works:

```
- name: restart server 9990
  supervisorctl: name='server_9990' state=restarted 
- wait_for: port=9990 delay=1

- name: restart server 9991
  supervisorctl: name='server_9991' state=restarted 
- wait_for: port=9991 delay=1
```

etc.

But I'd really like to do this in a loop. It seems that Ansible doesn't allow multiple tasks inside a loop (in this case, I need two tasks: supervisorctl and wait_for)

Am I missing a way to do this or is replicating these tasks for each instance of the server really the way to go?

Comment: are you running this as a playbook and role? If so, the playbook should run through hosts and a role only knows about its individual context.

Comment: So that's the thing, there are not HOSTS, they are processes within a single host.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's not possible with Ansible default functionality. I think your best bet would be to create [your own module](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_modules.html). I had seen that modules can call other modules, so you might be able to have a slim module which simply calls the `supervisorctl` module and then waits for the port to be ready. This module then could be called with `with_items`.

Another idea is to not use `supervisorctl` in the first place. You could run a `shell` or `script` task which does then manually call `supervisorctl` and waits for the port to open.